# url route in codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter, url-routing

I am developing multilanguage website using codeigniter. It is required to locate language at the beginning of the base url. what should I write in route.php, in  of view, and so on, so to have the final result to look like the following:

```
lang.mysite.com
```

lang must be changed all times the language is changed
Thanks a lot in advance.

Answer (score 1):

as far as i understand from your question:
it's not good to add language at the first of domain because browser deal with this language as sub domain, the best way to make url as the following www.somewebsite.com/en/controllerName/functionName 
 and this things will be done in codeigniter easily : read this please https://github.com/bcit-ci/CodeIgniter/wiki/URI-Language-Identifier thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

you can do it dynamically on your routes.php.

Like:-

```
require_once( BASEPATH .'database/DB'. EXT );
    $db =& DB();
    $query = $db->get( 'routes_urls' );
    $result = $query->result();
    foreach( $result as $row ){
         $route[$row->item_converted_url] = $row->item_url;
    }
```

routes_urls are saved into db